# running lm for many colums

Tags: r, statistics, apply, lm

I have a Df, the first column is phenotypic data and from the second to the last column is markers data. The rows are lines name.

```
pheno <- c(1450, 1700, 1300, 1333, 1545, 1755, 1100)
M1 <- c(0,2,0,0,0,0,2)
M2 <- c(2,2,2,2,0,0,2)
M3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,2,0)
M4 <- c(0,0,2,2,2,2,0)
dd <- data.frame(pheno, M1, M2, M3, M4)
```

I want to run lm, so my code is:

```
fit <- lm(dd$pheno ~ ., data = dd)
```

I think that this code computes a regression of pheno over all other columns, but the coefficients for M1(and all other columns) are not the same when running a regression individually for each column

```
fit2 <- lm(dd$pheno ~ dd$M1, data = dd)
```

Any idea of what i could be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The coefficients should **NOT** be the same as you add and subtract terms from the model @Maximiliano Verocai you're not doing anything "wrong" other than perhaps a little extra work since you can type `fit <- lm(pheno ~ ., data = dd) `

Comment: @BenBolker I dupe tagged with a post.  Please edit if you find a better one.  thanks

Comment: But the operation in both cases are the same, the only difference is that with fit all is done at a time and with fit2 I run lm one at a time.